# Strange issue with Dictionary and Locks C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, locking

At the moment I have a very strange issue regarding locking a dictionary. I have two different threads that access the dictionary, one thread puts in some entries, the other tries to read them out. All is well while making the entries, the strangest of problems occurs when I try to extract some values from the dictionary.

Here is what it looks like

```
 lock (myDictionary)
{
 //Add an entry here for a key.
}
```

// Retreival

```
lock(myDictionary)
{

 if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
 myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out store);
}
```

As soon as a thread enters the above code, the keys are not found. BUT if I write the following

```
lock(myDictionary)
{
  Console.WriteLine(myDicionary.Count)
 if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
   myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out store);
}
```

Out of nowhere I see the same dictionary containing the keys that were not found in the prior code. Now you guys can argue that what happened was the I/O delay caused enough time for the dictionary to store some values, but I donot have any timeouts or something that causes me to loose any processing, what this means till the dictionary contains some values to be extracted, next processing step will not occur and my program will wait till it gets some values. But unfortunately, this does not happen unless I put a Console.WriteLine... Anyone faced such situation before?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using `ContainsKey` *and* `TryGetValue`? Call `TryGetValue` unconditionally instead, and use the return value. Beyond that, it would be useful to see a short but complete program which demonstrates this problem...

Comment: How are you putting values in dictionary - r u using lock statement there as well as?

Comment: Sounds like a classic race condition. One thread is assigning and the other is reading... Who'll get there first? By changing the timing with a write to the console, you change the outcome of the race.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more code of how you put the values in and how you use the dictionary exactly.

Comment: When you replace the console.writeline with a sleep, does it also find the keys in the dictionary?

Comment: You are using the dictionary itself as the lock object. I do not think this is recommended.

Comment: If you are using a dictionary to move data between threads have you considered using a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd287191.aspx) which is designed for concurrent use?

Comment: If you are using .NET framework 4.0, you could try using a `ConcurrentDictionary`. All the public members of this class a thread-safe.

Comment: Agree with @spender: sounds like the classic race condition.

Comment: @Richard and @Elian, ConcurrentDictionary will not protect you against this kind of race, although it may reduce the amount of specific locking required... to solve this problem will require some other kind of synchronization.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, well my problem at hand is that I have a struct that needs to store some value extracted from the dictionary. If I am not wrong, TryGetValue will return null in case no key is found. We could argue that the struct could be made nullable, but at the moment I am restricted and change it to a nullable type.

Comment: @all, thanks for your comments guys. It turns out to be a timing issue.

Comment: @Wajih: TryGetValue will set the `out` parameter to the default value of the relevant type if it's not found. You don't need to make anything nullable.

Comment: @Jon, I did not know that, does that means I will not get a null but an object whose members are let's say to default values? Supposedly all zeros?

Comment: @Wajih: You'll get a *value* whose fields have the default values, yes. But the method will also return false, so you know to ignore that value.

Comment: @Jon, right Jon, thanks indeed. You is the MAN!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is most likely in the code that you are not showing. The type of issues that you describe is very common in multi-threading scenarios: everything comes down to timing, and timing is different when you change your code ever so slightly. In your particular case whatever value you are trying to access is there or not there depending on timing of what happening in other threads. It is simply possible that the value was not put there yet or was already deleted, when you code can't find it, but is present when you code can't see it.

It is impossible to say for sure, without seeing the rest of your code, especially the part that writes / deletes to / from the collection.

Few other things:

- you need to lock both read and write access
- even if you lock both read and write access you can't guaranty that a certain object is there unless you also use some other type of synchronization
- As other said using `ContainsKey` in combination with `TryGetValue` does not make much sense, the way you wrote it. 'TryGetValue' exists so that you do NOT need to call ContainsKey: if value is there it will be returned to you straight away and if it's not, the result of the method call will tell you this.

Comment: Thanks, it was just a timing issue. Had to put Monitor.Wait in a place and it worked fine. Thanks!